# How to develop a Facebook applications which can install on a user's page?

Tags: facebook, admin

I want to develop a Facebook application which can be installed on a user's system administration Facebook page.

Is it possible to make this application?

Comment: Not sure what "user's admin facebook page" if you mean on a user page, then the answer is no, if you mean on a Facebook page then the answer is yes

Comment: duplicate by the same user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316096/how-can-i-save-my-facebook-application-to-users-page

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**
You must first create applications in `http://facebook.com/developers`.

**Step 2:**
Fill the website link (your canvas link) in page tab.

**Step 3:**
Visit `http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=123456789`

Replace **123456789** with your **application ID** in the above [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

Comment: Thank for you reply, but if i want to install this application on user's admin pages then wht can i do?

Comment: so u neeed to create app that automatically adds page tab in admin page?

Comment: For example i am a developer and i want to sell my application, so i create it and i want to give one link to my client throw that he/she can click and application ask him their admin pages and if user click on admin page then it install on that page. I want this type of functionality.

Comment: yea u give him this url http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=123456789 ..this will add the app in his page

Comment: But i want to all user's admin page name and install on that page. for ex. i m admin of two page like ahmedabad and abc and i want my application to install on page abc. so what can i do?

Comment: If you visit the url http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=123456789....it list the pages they admin...they can select it

Comment: Sory i try it but it does not ask me for on which page i install. it only open the application.